# Trying to use javaScript setInterval to alternate content but it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, setinterval

i am trying to alternate the text of some elements and pass a parameter as shown in MDN. However, it doesn't work. Is the problem that i am messing jQuery and pure JavaScript? This is my [HTML](https://gist.github.com/liubomirwm/8334c1e7daa50c89ba9357408c161c71), this is my [CSS](https://gist.github.com/liubomirwm/124e1758986bd2a178c831ab7b4c5d36) and this is the [JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/liubomirwm/dde03a5cf684ff01c09e6144df700028).

```
$(function() {
    $("#top_navbar").on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
        $("#top_navbar > ul").css({
            "background-color": "black",
            "text-align": "center"
        });
    });

    $("#top_navbar").on("hidden.bs.collapse", function() {
        $("#top_navbar > ul").css("background-color", "transparent");
    });

    var headerStatus = 0;
    var h1Header = $("#header_content > div:first-of-type").filter("h1");
    var h3Header = $("#header_content > div:last-of-type").filter("h3");
    var firstParaHeader = $("#header_content > div:first-child").filter("p:first-of-type");
    var lastParaHeader = $("#header_content > div:first-child").filter("p:last-of-type");

    function changeHeaderContent(num) {
        switch (num) {
            case 0:
                h1Header.innerHTML = "The Trio";
                h3Header.innerHTML = "Creative design studio";
                firstParaHeader.innerHTML = "Creating the brand experience you & your audience deserve with Inbound Marketing.";
                lastParaHeader.innerHTML = "We already work with over 130 clients.";
                headerStatus = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                h1Header.innerHTML = "Create Brand";
                h3Header.innerHTML = "our true area of expertise";
                firstParaHeader.innerHTML = "We create simple, beautiful, and conversion focus designs for your customers.";
                lastParaHeader.innerHTML = "And delivered more than 210 design projects.";
                headerStatus = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    setInterval(changeHeaderContent, 5000, headerStatus);
});
```

Comment: Please post the actual code here.

Answer (score 1):

**Your `setInterval` instruction is only actually being executed once. At the point in time, `headerStatus` is `0`, so that's the value that is always used every time `changeHeaderContent` is invoked.**

In order to correctly pass your value to the function so that the value is updated upon each invocation, your syntax needs to be adjusted so that you call a function that calls the function you really want invoked with the parameter you need passed to that. This will cause a closure to be formed around `headerStatus` and you won't lose its value upon each invocation.

Adjusting the syntax allows for `changeHeaderContent` to close over `headerStatus` and then you reap the benefits of the closure.

```
setInterval(function(){
   // Call changeHeaderContent and pass the value of headerStatus to it:
   changeHeaderContent(headerStatus);
}, 5000);
```

Here's an example of how the two different versions of the syntax result in different results (see inline comments for explanations):

```js
(function(){
  var headerStatus = 0;

  function changeHeaderContent(num) {
    
    // Because headerStatus is used in this nested function and because it was declared
    // in a higher order function, there is a closure around headerStatus (this makes
    // headerStatus a "free variable"). However, the closure will only cause side-effects
    // if this nested funciton "outlives" its parent function's lifetime.
    
    switch (num) {
      case 0:
        headerStatus = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        headerStatus = 0;
        break;
      }
    console.log("headerStatus is now: " + headerStatus);
  }
  
  // Now that the nested function has termintated and we are back in the higher order
  // function's scope, the following syntax runs without any closures. Whatever the value of
  // headerStatus is, that value will be passed to the next invocation of changeHeader.
  
  // Based on the code, the value of headerStatus will be 0 (changeHeaderContent hasn't 
  // executed yet) and so changeHeaderContent will change it to 1. BUT... each time 
  // changeHeaderContent runs it won't be passed the updated value of headerStatus, this
  // syntax just passes it once and that original value is used for each subsequent invocation.
  
  // So, every time chagneHeaderContent is run, it's run with the original value of 
  // headerStatus, which was 0. Therefore, each invocation of changeHeaderContent will 
  // change it to 1.
  setInterval(changeHeaderContent, 1000, headerStatus);

}());
```

And, now with the suggested code:

```js
(function(){
  var headerStatus = 0;

  function changeHeaderContent(num) {
   
    switch (num) {
      case 0:
        headerStatus = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        headerStatus = 0;
        break;
      }
    console.log("headerStatus is now: " + headerStatus);
  }
  

  setInterval(function(){
    // Because the function that will be executed every 5 seconds contains a reference to
    // headerStatus (a free variable) and that function WILL outlive the higher order function
    // where headerStatus was declared, it forms a closure around it and EACH time the 
    // function runs, it will use the last known value of headerStatus, thus allowing the
    // old value to be used in determining the new value.
    changeHeaderContent(headerStatus)
  }, 1000);

}());
```

Comment: Is this the right way to pass an argument by reference in JavaScript?

Comment: Yep cause you're sending a closure as the first parameter. Just don't forget to fix the other stuff as well (getting DOM objects with jQuery and changing their values).

Comment: @LyubomirParvanov See my above comment to Lesotto.

Comment: @Scott Marcus, just thinking about this :) Actually the headerStatus is sent  as a reference (in a way) here along with the closure. Otherwise closure would always execute: function() {changeHeaderContent(0)}. Anyway, I guess Ljubomir is more interested here if this is the correct way to resolve situations when a variable needs to be sent as a reference rather than as a value. From my own experience, using closures is the best way. But I'm not an expert in JS, so I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: @LyubomirParvanov Make sure you don't forget to change other stuff from your code that has an issue. Cheers

Comment: @Lesotto That interpretation is not correct - `headerStatus` is passed by value. It's actually pretty simple. `headerStatus` is a primitive, so it is passed by value and it's value is 0. When `setInterval` is called with the parameters supplied outside of the function reference, you don't get a closure around them. When you reference the parameter from within the `setInterval` function, you do. That's what allows for `headerStatus` to not lose its value from one invocation to the next. Again, passing byRef or byVal is not related to this.

Comment: @Scott Marcus That's why I said that it is sent as a reference along with the closure, I wasn't reffering to the way it was used when the closure was executed.. setInterval reads the value as you mentioned and stores it in memory, but a closure uses the variable reference, like when ever you use the variable in the same scope or lower. But from within the closure when the closure is executed, only the value is sent from within the closure.

Comment: @Lesotto Sorry, but again, that explanation is just plain wrong. **If you use my solution or the OPs code, you get a copy of `headerStatus` (it's passed by value either way).** The difference is that in the OPs code there is NO closure around `headerStatus` and so after `changeHeaderContent` returns, that copy is garbage collected and another copy (of the original value) is used for the next iteration. With my solution, you have a closure around `headerStatus`. `setInterval` still gets a copy of `headerStatus`, but that copy is then what is used for all invocations of the callback function.

Comment: @Lesotto Because of the closure, the copy of  `headerStatus` that is initially provided to `setInterval` is not garbage collected and therefore all subsequent iterations get to use that shared copy. This is the effect closures have on free variables that they close over. It's not an issue of how the argument is passed, it's a matter of the scope of those passed arguments.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I guess we have different opinion on this one :) But I appreciate your attitude and opinion. Be that as it may, the final outcome of the code you written will definitely solve the problem with the value that comes into changeHeaderContent, and I'm glad we're on the same page there. Cheers

Comment: Good luck to you, but please understand that this isn't an opinion, it's how JavaScript works. ;)

Comment: Yep I see what you mean, and I agree, a variable is sent by value. But I think a closure, as a function, uses a reference of a variable to provide a value when calling another function at the point of being executed. And in this way, anywhere you send a closure, every variable within it is a reference pointer which is used to read from a memory location at the point when the closure is executed.

Comment: That's just not the way it works. In fact, **ALL arguments are passed by value in JavaScript**. Primitive variables store the actual data and object variables store a reference to where the object resides in memory. When a primitive variable is created, it stores the data. it has no idea how it will be used later and therefore, the value can't magically change from the actual data to the memory location of where the data is. When you pass an object variable, you are passing a COPY of the memory location for the object, so different object variables can all point to the same memory location.

Comment: Closures around primitives certainly can create the *illusion* of passing by reference, but that is not at all what is happening. It's just that the scope of the variable is widened so that multiple functions have access to the same copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think Scott Marcus is right with his code snippet. If you console.log your cases, you will notice that the parameter is obviously sent by value and not by reference, thus you are always ending with case 0. This way the function is passed as a closure and a reference to headerStatus is passed with it, rather then being read just one at the first interval.

so:

```
setInterval(function () {
    changeHeaderContent(headerStatus);
},5000);
```

And also for element content, you should probably use jQuery methods like text() or better html()
so:

```
case 0:
    h1Header.html("The Trio");
    h3Header.html("Creative design studio");
    ...

case 1:
    h1Header.innerHTML = "Create Brand";
    h3Header.html("our true area of expertise");
    ...
```

And this way for all elements you want to change.
And also this about getting elements via jQuery, I would suggest using context #header_content:

```
var h1Header = $('h1', $("#header_content"));
var h3Header = $('h3', $("#header_content"));
```

I have tested it locally like this and it works for me..

Comment: This has nothing to do with passing by reference or passing by value. It is simply a matter of the fact that the OPs code only executes `setInterval` one time and when that time occurs, `headerStatus` is 0. Changing the code to use another level of closure doesn't change how the variable is passed, it simply allows the value to be held in memory so that subsequent invocations can have access to the most recent value. Also, while using JQuery is fine, there is certainly no requirement for it, nor it is some kind of best-practice.